# what the difference between add and [] in the dictionary operation

Tags: c#, .net

Dictionary dict;

what's the diff between

dict.add(key, value) and dict[key] = value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dict[key] = value` will add the value if the key doesn't exist, otherwise it will overwrite the value with that (existing) key.

Example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(42, "foo");
Console.WriteLine(dict[42]);
dict[42] = "bar";  // overwrite
Console.WriteLine(dict[42]);
dict[1] = "hello";  // new
Console.WriteLine(dict[1]);
dict.Add(42, "testing123"); // exception, already exists!
```

Answer (score 5):

As Ahmad noted, `dictionary[key] = value;` will add the value if the key doesn't exist, or overwrite if it does.

On the other hand, `dictionary.Add(key, value);` will throw an exception if `key` exists.

Answer (score 2):

The `Add` operation will fail (throws `ArgumentException`) if the key already exists in the dictionary. The `[]` operation will either add the key if it doesn't exist or update it if the key does exist.